# how can i convert timestamp object to protobuf timestamp object

Tags: javascript, node.js, protobuf.js

The following is my firestore document. `utc` key in the object is Timestamp object.

```
{
  exit: {
    eventDateTime: {
      utc: Timestamp { _seconds: 1653024600, _nanoseconds: 0 },
      local: '2022-05-20T05:30:00+01:00'
    },
    _id: 'asdgasg1231231sds'
  }
}
```

I am trying to convert this JSON to protobuf like this using [`pb-util`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pb-util).

```
const fs = await db.collection('users').doc('qmkdBYSge7g8tEAkedu5').get();
const json_obj = fs.data()
const {struct} = require('pb-util');
const structValue = struct.encode(json_obj);
console.dir(structValue, { depth: null })
```

The output does not contain any Timestamp field, it converts the timestamp field into structValue.

```
{
  fields: {
    exit: {
      kind: 'structValue',
      structValue: {
        fields: {
          eventDateTime: {
            kind: 'structValue',
            structValue: {
              fields: {
                utc: {
                  kind: 'structValue',
                  structValue: {
                    fields: {
                      _seconds: { kind: 'numberValue', numberValue: 1653024600 },
                      _nanoseconds: { kind: 'numberValue', numberValue: 0 }
                    }
                  }
                },
                local: {
                  kind: 'stringValue',
                  stringValue: '2022-05-20T05:30:00+01:00'
                }
              }
            }
          },
          _id: { kind: 'stringValue', stringValue: 'asdgasg1231231sds' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So how can I convert the utc object to `kind: Timestamp`.

Comment: Just fyi: 1. there's no such thing as a "JSON object" 2. there is no JSON anywhere in your question, `fs.data()` returns an object.

Comment: @ChrisG just starting with node and javascript. let me know if I can change anything in question to make it more understandable.

Comment: According to this: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Value the Timestamp information is lost